# ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve '~antd/dist/antd.css'

Tags: reactjs

I have the issue ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve '~ antd / dist / antd.css', I can not fix it.
I tried to put the @import '~ antd / dist / antd.css'; . In css file.
Without success.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "time-clock",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "antd": "^4.9.2",
    "firebase": "^8.1.2",
    "polished": "^4.0.5",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
    
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`

### is only meant for css or scss files.

---

if you started your app with ->  `npx create-react-app yourAppName`

don't `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` into your `index.js` it will fail !!!

---

## Solution

DO NOT USE THE `GET STARTED DOCS`

Instead use the `Use in create-react-app` found [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)

1. Add `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';` to the top of `App.css` file
2. Then you should be able to use it on any component like `import { Button } from 'antd';`

[image]

Comment: Importing the file like `~antd/dist/antd.css` adds the stylesheet into head. Is there a way to avoid that and limit the `antd.css` file to App component only?

Answer (score 2):

Add in App.js

`import 'antd/dist/reset.css';`

[documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

**In file index.js**

```
import { ConfigProvider, theme } from 'antd';
```

**Wrap the App tag like this:**

```
<ConfigProvider theme={{
          algorithm: theme.darkAlgorithm
}}>
  <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```